# Woocommmerce show SKU in cart page

Tags: plugins

How to show the SKU next to the product name in the cart page of Woocommerce ?

tried to copy it from the Meta.php of single product but it breaks the page...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add the following code to your theme's `functions.php` file, or as a new plugin:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_in_cart_product_title', 'add_sku_in_cart', 20, 3);

function add_sku_in_cart( $title, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
  $sku = $values['data']->get_sku();
  return $sku ? $title . sprintf(" (SKU: %s)", $sku) : $title;
}
```

Comment: Cheers @GM, works a treat.

Answer (score 3):

For those finding this from google, here code that works on current versions (2.1+) of WooCommerce.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'add_sku_in_cart', 20, 3);

function add_sku_in_cart( $title, $values, $cart_item_key ) {
    $sku = $values['data']->get_sku();
    return $sku ? $title . sprintf(" (SKU: %s)", $sku) : $title;
}
```

The code example from G.M. did not work for me, and my rep is too low to comment on his post.

[Source](http://us-themes.com/support/topic/how-to-show-product-sku-in-woocommerce-cart/)